# How to hide URL values in PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url

I need to hide the url value in php as i have a booking site and users are able to edit their reservation through the URL if needed.

This is how the URL link looks like.

http://spiaggiasanmontano.it/booking/S12/2021-06-11/2021-06-12/0

i'm trying to remove the dates in the URL without breaking the code, any idea how i can do this?

And this is the route controller for it.

```
Route::get('/booking/{place_id}/{checkin}/{checkout}/{error_msg}', 'PagesController@createbooking')->name('user.createbooking');
```

Comment: why don't just use post request then??

Comment: basically replace the ::get with ::post right?

Comment: yeah, submit the form with post request and remove the route parameters if you don't want them in the url.

Comment: What **exactly** do you want to achieve? Where are you stuck? If such data is not relevant, why not simply remove it? Wouldn't it be better to use a single, unique identifier per booking, instead of multiple values?

Answer (score 2):

You can use laravel  `Encrypter` if you still wants to pass it in url with encrypted value instead of displaying orginal value

for example `checkin date`

pass encrypted date to url `encrypt(checkin)` value

```
encrypt(checkin)
```

then in your controller you can decrypt it

```
 $checkinDate= decrypt($checkin);
```

For example if have link like below in blade

```
<a href="{{route('user.createbooking',['palceid',encrypt($checkin)])}}"/>
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/encryption#using-the-encrypter

Comment: Is this the right way to write it in the URL route? : Route::get('/booking/{place_id}/{encrypt(checkin)}/{encrpt(checkout)}/{error_msg}', 'PagesController@createbooking')->name('user.createbooking');

Comment: @tamerjar.its not in route .you have to write it in blade where you pass url